# How to compare the time of encryption, cracking and verification elliptic curve problem in the same framework？

Tags: elliptic-curves, dsa, complexity

everyone! As a beginner, I would like to ask you a question. The best algorithm known for **cracking (done by anonymous snooper)** this problem （Discrete logarithm problem of elliptic curve or ECDSA）is Pollard’s rho method, and takes about the square root of πp/2, where p is the modulus. My questions are:
(1) Elliptical **encryption (done by designer and sender)** also takes time. Can this time also be expressed by modulus p?
(2) After the other party receives the information, it needs to be verified. This **verification (done by receiver of information)** also takes time. Can the time for verification also be expressed by modulus?
That is to say, can the above **three kinds of time** be put **into a frame for comparison**, and they are all compared with the parameters of elliptic curve (it is best to use modulus or order of Base point). My intention is to know which of these three times is the slowest and which is the fastest. But there is no doubt that the time to crack is definitely the slowest, and the time for encryption and verification is definitely much shorter. But how to quantify them? Is there any literature recommendation that compares them? It would be best to give a simple example. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be the number of points in the curve group and $p$ the size of the field. The quoted estimate for Pollard $\rho$ is $\sqrt {\pi n/2}$ which is the number of elliptic curve group operations required. To sign a ECDSA message (assuming that you already have your key pair) is an elliptic curve scalar point multiplication which takes (using [windowed double-and-add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Windowed_method)) $(1+\epsilon)\log n$ elliptic curve group operations. To verify is 2 elliptic curve scalar multiplications which is $(2+\epsilon)\log n$ elliptic curve group operations. If you have to generate a key pair, that adds another elliptic curve scalar multiplication.

The elliptic curve group operation will get harder with $p$ as well and the exact complexity is subject to a range of variant algorithms. An estimate of $O(\log^2p)$ for each elliptic curve group would not be hugely inaccurate though.

Comment: Almost. $N$ should be the cost of an elliptic curve group operation (which should be $O(\log^2 Z)$) rather than the order. Also you should have $T_{AT}=N\sqrt{\pi n/2}$. I'm also doing the mathematician thing of using $\epsilon$ to mean number that gets close to 0 for large $n$, in your example $\epsilon=1/4$ would work. I haven't explicitly checked your $T_{AT}$, but the numbers look right.

Comment: 1) $n\approx Z$ is true for almost all curves in cryptographic use. The book should make it clear that $\sqrt{\pi n/2}$ is the expected number of steps needed in Pollard $\rho$ (e.g. in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms introductory paragraph it quotes this many "steps"). Each step is a group operation and the cost $N$ will vary with the size of the group. 2) The cost of elliptic curve point multiplications can be read about here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Windowed_method

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. According to some literature, "If the **data size of modular multiplication is n**, and the complexity of one modular multiplication (MM) is `O(n^2logn)`, To sign a ECDSA message, there are 1 dot product operation, 1 modular inversion operation, and 2 modular multiplications. Nine MM equal 1 modular inversion, and the total operations are denoted as T, then `T=(logn+ 11)n^2`. To verify there are 2 dot products, 1 modular inversion, and 2 MM, then `N=(2logn+ 11)n^2` ".  Could you tell me why above are different from yours? Is it right? What is data size of modular?

Comment: I think that the author got things a bit mixed up. The main cost is the elliptic curve point multiply which would take $O(n^3)$ operations in their notation, I assume that this is what they are calling the "dot product operation". There's also a constant factor as elliptic curve group operations use several modular multiplies each (perhaps 12 or so https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_costs_of_operations_in_elliptic_curves ). The expressions should then be $T=(12n+11)n^2$ and $N=(24n+11)n^2$. The data size of the multiplication is $\log_2 Z$ in your notation or 256 in your example.

Comment: Mine are right and their's are not, though it would be best to consult an independent expert in such circumstances. In my view the best comparator is to say that $T_v/T_{en}\sim 2$ and $T_{AT}/T_{en}\sim\sqrt{\pi n/2}/\log n$.

Comment: If $N$ is the cost of an elliptic curve group operation (elliptic curve add), then it should be multiplied into all three expressions i.e. $T_{en}=N(1+\epsilon)\log_2 n$, $T_v=N(2+\epsilon)\log_2 n$ and $T_{AT}=N\sqrt{\pi n/2}$ and so the ratio is as I quoted.

Comment: Your expression is very clear now. Thank you, Daniel! However, I have another question in next following comment (due to length limitation).

Comment: Paper “Remote Timing Attacks Are Still Practical”:
Parties select a private key d uniformly from 0 < d < n and publish the corresponding public key D = [d]G. To sign a message m, parties select nonce k uniformly from 0 < k < n then compute the signature (r, s) by
r = ([k]G) mod n       (1)
s = (h(m) + dr)k^−1 mod n.  (2)
I wonder if Ten=N(1+ϵ)log2n **already includes the modular inverse computation in equation (2)**, or it **just describes the calculation in equation (1)**, because it seems that the method Double-and-add only shows how to compute dP (i.e., [d]G here) in your provided link.

Comment: The cost of a modular inverse is less than $N$ (elliptic curve arithmetic will involve at least one modular division). Adding a single modular inverse (and multiplication, and addition) can be absorbed into the $\epsilon$ term.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel! But would you please tell me how to determine the value of ϵ. Recall that you use ϵ to mean number that gets close to 0 for a large n in one of above comments. In fact, I believe that the modular inverse computation is not negligible.

Comment: For windowed point multiplication, $\epsilon$ can be taken to be $2/(\log\log n-\log\log\log n)$.

Comment: Thank you! I take all the formulas you provided together (i.e., Ten=N*(1+ϵ)*log2n, Tv=N*(2+ϵ)*log2n and TAT=N*√((π*n)/2), ϵ=2/(loglogn−logloglogn), N=(logn)^2) and find that you are most likely right because if we set n = 2^256, then TAT= 2.79498*10^43;Ten=2.34881*10^7;Tv=4.02653*10^7. Then three questions arise: (1) I'd like to know what are the units of these results, I want to  yield results whose units are second, or day or other units related to time; (2) if I drop N from all formulas, then what are their units? (3) Which literature or link can we find that  ϵ=2/(loglogn−logloglogn)?

Comment: 1) When we say $N=O(\log^2 n)$, there's a n implicit constant, depending on the constant used this could be interpreted as  bit operations of word operations. You'd then need some measure of bit operations or word operations per second of the computer in question 2) "elliptic curve group operations" 3) plug $w=1/(\log\log n-\log\log\log n)$ into the formula $2^w-2+n/w$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Windowed_method ).

Comment: Thank you, Daniel! (1) loglogn =Log2^(Log2^n), logloglogn=Log2^(Log2^(Log2^n)). Are both equalities right? (2) Plug w=1/(loglogn−logloglogn) into the formula 2w−2+n/w, and then we can get what? I still don't understand. It seems that we cannot derive ϵ=2/(loglogn−logloglogn). Could you please explain it in more detail?

Comment: In the wikipedia description, it says that In the (notation of this question) point multiplication takes $\log_2 n$ elliptic curve doubles and $2^w-2+\log n/w$ elliptic curve adds. With $w=1/\log\log n -\log\log\log n$ we have $2^w=\log n/\log\log n<\log n/(\log\log n-\log\log\og n)$ and $\log n/w=\log n/(\log\log n-\log\log\og n)$ so that $$2^w-2+\log n/w<2\epsilon(\log n)$. (In my previous post, I neglected to convert the wikipedia $n$ init the question's $\log n$).

Comment: (1) w=1/loglogn−logloglogn or w=loglogn−logloglogn？I think you mean w=loglogn−logloglogn instead of w=1/loglogn−logloglogn. (2) "I neglected toconvert the wikipedia n in it thequestion′s \log n$". You mean that 2w−2+n/w in  wikipedia, in my notation, it actually 2w−2+logn/w? Could you  please tell me why? Thank you!

Comment: (1) $w=\log\log n-\log\log\log n$ my apologies; that was remiss of me. (2) In the wikipedia article: "The entire complexity for a $n$-bit number is measured as $n+1$ point doubles and $2^w−2+\frac {n}{w}$ point additions". We've been using $n$ to represent the group order which is a $\log n$ bit number.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel! Recall that I asked a question about the unit of the result. Acoording to a literature, "Operating a modern Core
class possessor that can perform 2.4 billion 64-bit operations per second (Intel
Corporation, 2009)".  Because N=(Log2[n])^2, if we set n = 2^256, we can derive that TAT=N*√((π*n)/2)= 2.79498*10^43. My question is, can we think that TAT= (2.79498*10^43)/(2.4*10^9) seconds?

Comment: Probably the best thing to do at this point is to look at this page of performance numbers: https://cr.yp.to/ecdh/reports.html the cycles column gives the number of cycles for $T_{en}$, the field size gives $p$. Dividing the cycles value by the clock speed of the processor would give a time in seconds. The formulae for $T_{at}/T_{en}$ and $T_v/T_{en}$ should then suffice for the other values.

Comment: It considered only $kP$ which is the dominant term. The relative cost of the other operations is both implementation and architecture dependent and so not simple to include.

Comment: Dainel, I'd like to consider them. We know: (1) Tsign = 2 ×T_MUL +T_INV +T_kP; Tverify = 2×T_MUL +T_INV + 2×T_kP. (we omit HASH operations here); (2) according to "Handbook of Applied Cryptography", in page 72: Bit complexity of Modular multiplication is O((lg n)^2), Modular inversion's bit complexity is also O((lg n)2), where n is the number of points in the curve group. In addition, according to your previous statement, scalar multiplication's (i.e., kP) bit complexity is O(lg n) . Thus, we can say that  Tsign = 3*(lg n)^2+lg n;  Tverify = 3*(lg n)^2+2*lg n.Do you think this is correct?

Comment: No. I previously said that scalar multiplication has a complexity of $O(\log n)$ elliptic curve group operations. I also said that an elliptic curve group operation uses several modular multiplies (in the range 9-17) and so the cost of scalar multiplication is $O((\log n)^3$. Thus we can say maybe Tsign~= 12*(lg n)^3+3*(lg n)^2; Tverify~= 24*(lg n)^3+3*(lg n)^2, but this is very implementation and architecture dependent. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_costs_of_operations_in_elliptic_curves

Comment: It's because you have taken a very rough estimate for the number of bit operations and divided it by the rate for performing 64-bit machine instructions. These include instructions such as multiplying two 64-bit integers together which might represent up to 2^12 bit operations. Other instructions can take more bit operations and there are other effects from parallelism and fast multiplication algorithms. As seen in a previous link, roughly 3 million cycles is an example of the time for a scalar multiplication on a  256-bit curve.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that I can help you with that. There are so many implementation and architecture variations with multiple trade-offs that I wouldn't wish to nominate a single definitive choice.